# ImageView's wrap_content not working with Glide

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm testing the glide for loading the images in my project.

I created the following layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:background="#550000ff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

When I load the image with the `imageView.setImageResource(int)` it loads correctly (see screenshot below)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pen_logo);
}
```

[image]

But when I load it with glide the image get expanded ignoring the **wrap_content** layout params:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.pen_logo).into(imageView);
}
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: set `android:ScaleType="fitXY"` and try

Comment: With fitXY the result is like in the first capture, but with an smaller image (maybe it is ignoring scaling the image up due to the screen density?)